# In Clojure, what does `&` mean in function/macro signature?

Tags: clojure, macros, lisp

I saw the usage of `&` in Clojure function signature like this (http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/thread):

```
(thread & body)
```

And this:

```
(doseq seq-exprs & body)
```

Does that means the function/macro can accept a list as variable? I also find `*` is often used to mean multiple parameters can be accepted, like this:

```
(do exprs*)
```

Does anyone have ideas about the difference between `&` and `*` in function/macro signature? Is there any documentation to explain this syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In clojure [binding forms](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#binding-forms) (`let`, `fn`, `loop`, and their progeny), you can bind the rest of a binding vector to a sequence with a trailing `&`. For instance,

```
(let [[a b & xs] (range 5)] xs) ;(2 3 4)
```

Uses of `*` and other uses of `&` are conventions for documenting the structure of argument lists.

Answer (score 15):

It means that there can be multiple parameters after the ampersand, and they will be seen as a seq by the function. Example:

```
(defn g [a & b]
  (println a b))
```

Then if you call:

```
 (g 1 2 3 4)
```

it will print out `1 (2 3 4)` (a is 1, b is a sequence containing 2, 3 and 4).

Comment: oh, so it is like the `...rest` parameter in JavaScript? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have ideas about the difference between & and * in function/macro signature? Is there any documentation to explain this syntax?

There is no real difference between exprs* and & body. The former some sort of informal description inspired by regular expression and the latter more how it is often written in the code.